# who can tell me the support pix_format of all AVCodec in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Like the title, I want to know the support pix_format of all AVCodec in FFmpeg.

Like mpeg1video, I know the pix_format which support is just PIX_FMT_YUV420P. So what about other AVCode? Where I can find the define about them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an individual encoder run

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=encoder_short_name
```

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=libx264
```

The fourth line will have

```
Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p yuv422p yuvj422p yuv444p yuvj444p nv12 nv16 nv21
```

---

On bash, you can run

```
for enc in $(ffmpeg -hide_banner -encoders | grep -i "V[\.|F]" | \
             cut -s -f3 -d" " | tail -n +2); \
do ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=$(echo $enc) | grep "Encoder\|pixel" >> encpxfmt.txt; done;
```

to get full list in a textfile.