# FFmpeg formats list with alpha support

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, alpha-transparency

**I am looking the list of FFmpeg codecs which support the alpha channel.**
seems that there is no description of codec list with alpha in FFmpeg.

I am interested only in decoding files with alpha, not for encoding one. 
Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. You want a list of decoders which support decoding an input with alpha?

Comment: yes, you are right.
I would like to get the list of decoders which are supports alpha channel.

Comment: Adapt the shell command in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47029343/5726027) for decoders, and examine the text file.